# Backup zipping, continue where I left off

Tags: backup, file-archiver

I have an old filebackup that takes up space. I want to zip it so I still have it, but reduce its size.

Its size is massive, so ideally I want to find a way to create this zip backup in chunks, creating part of the backup in steps.

Is there a way I can create a backup, preferably using an archive, that I can abort, and resume later?

I'm using Windows 10. Would love to have it in that. Also, I don't mind deleting the files in the process, as long as the folder structure is in tact in the zip file.

Comment: Does it have to be a .zip file? Did you consider alternative space recovering solutions that don't even involve making an archive? Can you explain why it has to be done in sessions instead of just letting it run for a few hours or longer?

Comment: Sounds dangerous. As soon as it's in a single file, your chances of losing it increase.

Comment: @Romen its about 700 gig of data, I don't want to keep my pc running for a long time just to finish this, but only run it while I work behind it. It takes days, not a few more hours.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't really care for that. Its a backup of my pc's state of 5 years ago and I only keep it just in case I need something from back then, which a few months ago, I was really happy to still have this backup, but I need a bit more space on the drive to store a large project for the duration of a few months. I've considered compressed files too, but it takes a long time to setup too and doesn't create a strong compression like 7z does either.

Comment: In general ZIP files don't need to be created in one step. When adding files later only the central directory table at the end has to be moved but all the already compressed files can stay where they are. So you could create the ZIP file from the first files and if that is done delete the zipped files. Then add more and more files to the ZIP and delete them afterwards. Of course this assumes the files to be zipped are not too large.

Comment: Your replies are good information to add to the question so people don't miss it in the comments. Also please answer the other questions too. Why does it have to be a zip? Do you need to access files from the archive randomly? Does it actually need to be an archive? Is buying a whole new drive to store this backup not a viable option? Did you explore full-disk compression as another option? Do you actually need to keep *everything* or can you sort though those folders and delete stuff?

Comment: @Romen I stated it in my question. Preferably using an archive, but its not a must. Also, I cannot add another harddisk to my computer and I really do want to keep the files on this disk and not place them on an external drive. My main problem is going to be that if I don't see the files, I will forget that I have them, an archive is easily opened, which is why I prefer that, but its not a must.

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment so just to be sure you answered this too: Did you go through the whole backup to make sure all unnecessary data is deleted? Like you usually don't need to keep Program Files or the Windows folder from a PC backup. Even if you did, you could delete *most* things in the subfolders.

Comment: And yes, I did explore folder wide disk compresson from windows (Aka compressed folders) Its something I can do, but takes as long to create as a 7zip archive, and I can't really abort it to later resume it. It also does not nearly compress as well as a 7z file. For example, I have a folder AMD of 1 GB. folder compression makes it 800 mb, 7z 500mb.

Comment: No, the backup does contain files that are not really useful, but I want to keep them there. Shifting through them is going to take even longer than just creationg the 7z archive. But my question is more in terms of: resuming the task, not to find alternatives. Also because at work, this sometimes happens too, and if I can learn about a way to create an archive in such way that I can later resume it, that would greatly help me.

Comment: I am just trying to make sure all the bases are covered. If you can reduce the total size of the files that need to be compressed then your need for extra space might entirely go away or be possible to solve with a new solution. I strongly suggest that you go through that "full backup" and just delete the Windows folder right away. That's like 30 GB deleted instantly that you'll never miss. There are other folders that can consume lots of space on junk that you won't miss. Like C:\Temp and some things in the AppData folder. You don't have to go over it with a fine-tooth comb.

Comment: If you have a fast, solid desktop machine, an outside the box solution might be to set up a virtual machine and run the Zip operation there. Let it run to completion. A VM will connect with in and out disks.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best option seems to just use 7zip right now. In the 7zip window, you can press pause to pause the current operation.

In the pause state, you can hibernate the computer (not shutdown) and once booted up again, you can resume the operation.

This is the approach I'm using right now.